# MapsUI always shows "own location" marker at LatLng 0,0

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapsui

I have the issue with MapsUI 2.0.3 that the marker of my own location is always at 0,0 west of Africa. Clicking the focus on own location button obviously also moves me there.

I did add coarse and fine location permissions to manifest and do get permission to access locations, but "you are here" is always 0,0.

I then downloaded the MapsUI repository, and tried the samples, which show the same behavior, mostly. When the map loads, it shows position at 0,0. If I drag the map slightly, the marker slowly moves to my correct position. If I (in the samples) reload the same sample or another one, the marker remains stuck at 0,0, even when I drag the map. In summary, I can "fix" the 0,0 marker by interacting with the map but only once.

My device does have gps location enabled, and other location using apps work fine. This including other home made Xamarin forms apps, so this is an issue for MapsUI only.

It failing for both samples and own code makes this a bit confusing.
Does this ring a bell for anyone? Seems a bit strange to say the least.

Note that this also fails on the xamagin/android device emulator with a set position. Just mentioning this as a "fun" extra detail, map longpress event will never fire on my device, but does work on the emulator. I saw someone else, a long time back, complaining about that same issue, and a developer commenting on it being fixed in 2.0, while I see it in 2.3. All in all MapsUI seems like an extremely rich system that I would love to use, but which has weird little bugs and poor support.

The xaml for adding the mapview

```
<StackLayout>
  <mapsui:MapView x:Name="mapView" IsMyLocationButtonVisible="True" />
</StackLayout>
```

And the c# setup

```
void start()
{
  var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();
  if(status==PermissionStatus.Denied) return;  
  
var map = new Mapsui.Map
  {
    Transformation = new MinimalTransformation(),CRS = "EPSG:3857"};
    
    var tileSource = new HttpTileSource(new GlobalSphericalMercator(),
      "https://tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png? 
      apikey=xxxxxxxxx",new[] { "a", "b", "c" }, name: "OpenStreetMap");
    
    var tileLayer = new TileLayer(tileSource) { Name = "Carto Light" };
    map.Layers.Add(tileLayer);
    mapView.Map = map;
}
```

Comment: Hi, when you get the location, whether using `MoveToRegion` to move to the location. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map#move-the-map

Comment: I just noticed that you are referring me to xamarin.forms.map guides?! This question is about MapsUI and not forms.map.

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding that. I will check the `MapsUI`, if good news will update here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not knowing why `MyLocationButton` not works, but there is a **workaround** to make the current location to show in **MapsUI**.

There is a `UpdateMyLocation` method inside [MyLocationLayer](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/master/Mapsui.UI.Forms/Objects/MyLocationLayer.cs),then we can use this method to show the current location programmatically.

In addition, you could use [Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android#using-geolocation) to get the current location.

Code as follows:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
  
    var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

    if (location != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
    }

    mapView.MyLocationLayer.UpdateMyLocation(new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), true);
}
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: That is an interesting solution, thanks! My problem right now is that I was in the process of migrating away from Forms.Maps, for various reasons, and seeing these issues (mylocation, longpress) I worry they are only the top of the iceberg, and it would be horrible finding a more serious breaking issue further along in the process.
Thanks anyway for this fix. Might give it another go, and hope other issues can be circumvented as well. Will leave question open for a few days and then mark as answer.

Comment: @JoeTaicoon Thanks, that's great! I also look forward to more suggestions from others.

Comment: Is there a way to zoom or scale in programmatically?